# Android Xml layout issue to shift down the textView

Tags: android, xml, layout, responsive-design, android-toolbar

I'm not sure why the layout design looks correct but on the emulator.
check the screenshots and code please. almost as if there is something is on top of something else the causes the toolbar and textView to shift downwards a little. I tried changing or removing the elements over and over again without luck. any help will be appreciated

Thank you.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/BackGround"
tools:context=".ReportError">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="@string/report"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline21"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:text="@string/Choose_image"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline21"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:alpha="3.0"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline21"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewImage" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewE"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:text="@string/enter_a_detailed_description_of_the_problem"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline21"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.539"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtdata"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:alpha="3.0"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="start|top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline21"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewE" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnbrowse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="@string/browse"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline22"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline23"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.377"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtdata"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnupload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
    android:text="@string/upload"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline22"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline21"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.765"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline23"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtdata"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline20"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.93" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline22"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.98" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline23"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtdata"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.484"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtdata"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewE" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Consider adding @layout/toolbar to your question as well.

Comment: sure thank you @ΓDΛ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root layout. or to your root `theme`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/BackGround"
tools:context=".ReportError">
```

**fitsSystemWindows**

> it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents don't overlay
> the system windows.